# react-scripts 2.1.8 --> 3.0.0 breaks redux "connected" tests?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-scripts

Following the simple guidelines for testing connected components found [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components) I've had tests of this format passing for months:

```
import ConnectedFaultReport, {FaultReport} from [...];
describe('FaultReport (connected) component tests', () => {
  let container = shallow(<ConnectedFaultReport  />);
  it('Should render the Redux connected component', () => {
    expect(container.length).toEqual(1)
  });
})
```

After upgrading react-scripts to 3.0.0 I now get the dreaded:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(FaultReports)..."
```

error. I've had to go through all my simpler connected tests and implement:

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";

const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const store = mockStore({});

  describe('FaultReport (connected) component tests', () => {
    let container = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedFaultReport />
      </Provider>
    );
    it('Should render the Redux connected component', () => {
      expect(container.length).toEqual(1)
    });
  })
```

I am fine with `redux-mock-store` but this is a massive amount of churn and refactoring. Am  I the only person seeing this after upgrading `react-scripts`?

@markerikson: I was *not* passing `store` as a prop previously. The upgrades enacted are below (I saved the output of `ncu` this time as the same thing happened on a separate project). Just noticed that `react-redux` got bumped a full version as well...

```
react-redux               ^6.0.1  →   ^7.0.3
react-scripts              2.1.8  →    3.0.0
enzyme-adapter-react-16  ^1.11.2  →  ^1.12.1
```

Comment: What version of React-Redux are you using, and did you happen to upgrade that at the same time you upgraded `react-scripts` ?  Also, were you previously passing `store` as a prop to `<ConnectedFaultReport>` ?

Comment: @markerikson see edited question above - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually surprised that shallow rendering `<ConnectedFaultReport>` worked at all with React-Redux v6.  We had [several users report that that stopped working entirely](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1161).  Plus, if you *weren't* passing a store as a prop *or* wrapping it in a `<Provider>`, then the existing test *should* fail - a connected component *always* requires a store, period.

As of v7, you should be able to pass a store directly as a prop again (as with v5 and earlier), like `<ConnectedFaultReport store={store} />`.

Comment: It's been a while, but I recall trying to send a store as a prop and having the compiler yell at me. I may have been sending a plain object instead of a mocked store, it's been a while. It seemed to be ok as long as the root was wrapped in a `<Provider>`. 

It works fine now, I'll stick with wrapping directly with `<Provider>` going forward though I will try the "store as prop" today, it may mean fewer SLOCs. Thanks!

Comment: Sending the mocked store as props works great - thanks.